# Scalar obtained from division of magnitudes of two vectors.

Tags: vectors

Consider we are having a scalar vector multiplication. Is it correct in concept (numerically it makes sense) to compute the scalar as division of the magnitude of the obtained vector from multiplication and the magnitude of the vector that was originally a parameter? For example, trying to compute the mass as a division of magnitudes between F(force) and a(acceleration) vectors. Numerically I know this fits, as well as scalar component division of the two vectors, but it would seem redundant to compute both divisions, since the same scalar is applied to both components in the first place. I'm trying to understand what would be the correct approach from a mathematical approach. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you know that, for example, $F=ma$.

Then you can find $m$ by dividing one specific component or the magnitude of the vectors as you suggest.

Both methods are mathematically correct.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply :)

Comment: Glad to be of help.